# How can I make my mouse middle click act like the space bar?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, mouse

I want to (temporarily) make it so that clicking the middle mouse button of my 3-button mouse act like the spacebar on the keyboard. Is there anyway to do this easily? I would only do it for using some applications, so I would be changing it back and forth often. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: What does "act like the spacebar" mean? Do you want a space character to be printed or do you want to, for example, scroll a webpage? What applications are you referring to?

Comment: I mean I want the computer to think the middle mouse button is the spacebar. I want to use it for web browsing, gaming, Audacity, etc.